# Dropbear SSH on Cygwin won't allow passwordless login

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I am using Dropbear SSH running on Cygwin, on Windows 7, on a VMware virtual machine, on Windows 8.1. On my physical OS I have Cygwin and I am trying to get passwordless login using openssh on Cygywin. To build it I had to pass `LIBS="-lcrypt -lz"` to make in order to get it to pick up libcrypt and zlib.

After building and installing it, I generated my client's key pair on my physical OS with `ssh-keygen` and copied it into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` per Dropbear's manpage, and then I started Dropbear with `dropbear -EF`. After certifying that the Dropbear daemon on the VM started fine and showed up on the Windows Task Manager, I tried to connect to the VM and get a message saying `Permission denied (publickey)`. I tried disabling all login options except for public key login, recompiled Dropbear, and it still won't work.

Running the client with the verbose option gives me this:

```
Huachimichu@rootrockshooter ~
$ ssh -v -l povrch -x 192.168.91.128
OpenSSH_6.5, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.91.128 [192.168.91.128] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2014.63
debug1: no match: dropbear_2014.63
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA cc:62:15:b3:5a:4b:07:2c:e2:ef:03:ef:91:b6:9e:23
debug1: Host '192.168.91.128' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Huachimichu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Basically your question is about adding publicKey authentication to a Windows box ... not really the place (Ok, "cygwin", but still on Windows)

Comment: I tried using password authentication, but it didn't work, after typing the correct Windows password for my account it still wouldn't authenticate. I intend to set up SSH on my home computer because I would very much prefer to use lightweight SSH to log in and move files around, as well as straightforward SCP to transfer files from a remote computer. I usually deal with files on an NTFS-formatted external drive sometimes in the order of 300 GB, so using it on Linux would be extremely slow and as a result I believe I have to use Windows.

Comment: Password authentication is probably disabled in your server configuration. Post the content of the `sshd_config` file.